# Content is not allowed in prolog. via Hermes JMS with good xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jms

I work with Hermes to send some JMS files. I have lot of JMS queues to send different type of message to my server. So, I have a problem with one of these queues. To facilitate my explanations, the queue with problem is queue 1. 
So I send an `xml` in queue 1 and there is a `SAXParseException`. I read lot of topics about that, so I verified first line, `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` in my `xsd` and `xml`. And there is not my `xml` file the problem, because this same file in queue 2 it's all ok. It makes me mad !! Please, someone can help me ?

The exception :

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, your could be interested in [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox) which is simpler to use and configure than hermes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searches, I found !
The `xsd`file encoding changed to UTF-8 BOM. So when I send the file to my server, specials caracters appears of the beginning. I changed the Encoding to UTF-8 w/o BOM and it's ok !